# Asp.Net Web Api and using generated cs files using xsd.exe as models

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

we have few existing schemas that we want to use as models in our WebApi classes so we did the following steps.

1. used xsd.exe to generate the .cs (CustomerlookupRequest) files
2. Set the config to use xmlserializer

we see a null in the request in the api's action method, has someone encountered this before ?

```
    public void Post()
    {
        var stronglyType = this.Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<CustomerLookupRequest>().Result;

    }
```